# How to populate Excel cell with multiple Item from drop down list

Tags: excel

I have an Excel table where I need to fill a cell with a list of items but when I select them from the drop-down menu(populated with list from data Validation) and you can find an example below:

Items in the drop-down menu - list:

```
Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5
```

I need to select for example `Item 2`, `Item 4`, and `Item 5` and in my cell, the final value should look like this:

```
Item 2, Item 4, Item 5
```

Regards.

Comment: You need vba. No multiselect option to data validation list.

Comment: Example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("MYCELLPOSITION")) Is Nothing Then
   If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
      GoTo Exitsub
   Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Newvalue = Target.Value
      Application.Undo
      Oldvalue = Target.Value
         If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
         Else
            If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
               Target.Value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & Newvalue
               Target.Value = Replace(Target.Value, "MYVALUEIWANTTOCHANGE", "")
         Else:
            Target.Value = Oldvalue
         End If
      End If
   End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The code above did the job.